# Calling Redirect::back() from a other function does not work. Laravel 4

Tags: redirect, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and some times it's hard to undestand waht's happening.

I have a code for validate a form. If I use it in a function it works right, but dosn't work the Redirect:back() if a call it from a other function. I want to reuse the code for all forms, but can't refactor.

This is the code (not working, does't redirect, continue executing code if validation fails)

```
private function formValidation($data ,$rules ,$error_name = 'user', $message = 'Hay errores en el formulario')
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        Session::Flash('message' , $message);
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator,$error_name)->withInput();
    }
    else
        return $validator;
}


public function loginPost()
{
    $this->formValidation(Input::all(),User::$rules_login);
    ..........
```

This code works fine, it redirects if validation fails:

```
public function loginPost()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),User::$rules_login);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        Session::Flash('message' , 'Hay errores en el formulario');
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator,'user')->withInput();
    }
    .............
```

Can anybody help me plese? Really I want to call it from another class, but after see that does not work I call fron a private function.

I try calling Redirect:to('login', $data, $rules...) and with Redirect::route too, still not working.

Tanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, so I can refactor ;)

```
private function formValidation($data ,$rules , $message = 'Hay errores en el formulario')
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        MyHelpers::sendSessionFlashMessages(array('message' => $message)); // Send a Session::flash with css information
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator, 'user')->withInput();
    }

    return $validator;
}

public function loginPost()
{
    if (get_class($response = $this->formValidation(Input::all(),User::$rules_login)){ === 'Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse')
        return $response;
    }
...................... rest of the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses the return value of the `loginPost()` method to determine what the response to the browser is. However, that method doesn't return the redirect - `formValidation()` does. So what happens is that `formValidation` returns a redirect, and then it gets ignored completely. If you put the redirect in the `loginPost()` method, it should work straight away.

Comment: Hi Joel. I know that it works if I call it from loginPOST() method. But there are a lot of forms, not just in UsersController but in a lot of controllers. I want to know if there a way to refactor using this private function (really it will be a static function in a class so I could call it in other cotrollers) and using another way for calling Redirect, maybe passing in fromValidation() a path variable.

Comment: Ultimately, if you want to redirect from ``loginPost()``, you'll have to return a redirect from it - and the same goes for any similar method. I may be wrong, but I don't think there's a way around it. You could check, I suppose, if the returned value is what you wanted (e.g. a validator, or a truth value) and return the returned redirect otherwise. Sorry that I don't know of any better way.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I dont understand yet why it does not work :( If I put a echo insted the return I show in the screen that the path is http://laravel.test/login, that's the right path. But code execution continues, doesn't stop after this return.

Comment: Laravel doesn't care about what the ``formValidation`` method returns. You call the method, but you don't do anything with its return value. So the redirect just disappears into nothingness.